# WordCloud Not Enough Memory Available Error

Tags: word-cloud

I'm having issues with [`WordCloud`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WordCloud.html) giving me the error `Not enough memory available to compute the word cloud.` This happens even on extremely simple word clouds, on both of my computers (running 12.0.0 on macOS 10.15.2 for both), and has survived multiple reboots of both my computers and just the kernel. It does seem to work fine in the cloud.

When I call `MemoryAvailable[]` I get `9 916 493 824` which seems to pretty much agree with the amount of memory that my Activity Monitor reports as being free (I have 24 GB installed).

```
WordCloud[{"one", "two", "three", "one"}]
```

[image: Results of trying to compute word cloud.]

I've had issues in the past with things like `FindPeaks` where they seem to have downloaded a bad update and break, but I don't see a paclet for `WordCloud`, though I may be looking in the wrong spot.

**EDIT 1:**

In response to a comment, I've added the result of `?WordCloud`.

[image: Result of ?WordCloud]

Comment: What response do you get from ?WordCloud

Comment: @bills I've added the result to the post.

Comment: I had been wondering if maybe the function had been overwritten by something else, but it seems intact. Your example WordCloud[{"one", "two", "three", "one"}] works fine here, so I would probably contact Wolfram to see if they have any ideas.

Comment: @bills Okay, will do!

Comment: I running both V11.3 and V12.0 on MacOS 10.13.4. I tried you code on both and the expected word clod graphic instantly on both. I suspect something must corrupt on your system, but have no idea as to what.

Comment: Sorry, no answer but I have exactly the same problem in two different computers (with a lot of memory).
Even the help example doesn't work when I validate them.

Comment: Yes, I've encounted with similar problem, but can't re-produce now.